# Is there anyway to make it difficult to bookmark a page in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, google-chrome-extensions

I have a problem with seeing too many interesting pages and bookmarking them to look at later. I end up with way too many bookmarks to ever get through. Ideally I want to institute a 'one in, one out' policy for bookmarking, so that to add a new bookmark I have to delete an existing one. Are there any extensions for Chrome that do anything like this?

Comment: What I do is just bookmark it, and sort them into my folders (or delete them) when my list gets bigger than 42 bookmarks. In the long run, you'll simply get tired of the extension's in-the-way behavior, and "temporarily" disable it.

Comment: One solution, step away from the computer. ;-> Actually you need to break your habit of bookmarking everything interesting you look at on the web, start making better decisions, if it is interesting, skim the page and then make the decision to keep it or not. I use a temp bookmarks folder for this, I review it every so often when I am bored and clean it up. What is the point of bookmarking it if you never use the bookmark. Quite a conundrum.

Answer (score 1):

Rockmelt actually has this function in it as a View Later tab you could possibly get some code or where to start from their source. Rockmelt uses Chromium as a base, not sure how the tab is implemented though but it does exactly what you want.